# Write a lambda expression to get a list of properties from a list of objects

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following two objects:

```
ProjectPrimitives:
   Name
   ProjectId
   StartDate

ProjectDetails
   ProjectPrimitives
   Description
   Location
   // Other details
```

In my application I have a `List<ProjectDetails>` and would like to parse all of the primitives from them to get a `List<ProjectPrimitives>` using a lambda expression. Effectively, I would like to replace this:

```
var primList = new List<ProjectPrimitives>();
foreach(ProjectDetails pd in myDetailsList)
{
   primList.add(pd.primitives);
}
```

I have tried a few things but cannot find the right syntax, if this is in fact possible using lambda statements. One thing I've tried is:

```
var prims = myList.Where(i => i.primitives).ToList();
```

But the compiler is expecting a boolean inside the `Where()` function and I don't know what else to put there.

Comment: Is `ProjectPrimitives` a collection, or a single item?

Comment: @Selman22 despite how its name sounds (chosen by another developer) it is a single item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `ProjectDetails.primitives` is a single `ProjectPrimitives`, you need [`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) to transform the list from `ProjectDetails` to `ProjectPrimitives`:

```
var prims = myList.Select(i => i.primitives).ToList();
```

If it is a collection, such as `List<ProjectPrimitives>`, you need [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var prims = myList.SelectMany(i => i.primitives).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference. While "ProjectPrimitives" is plural, it was a single object, so in my use case `Select` was what I needed.